# Plotting pie chart in python after grouping the columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, pie-chart

I am new to python and matplotlib and looking for some help.

I have following sample data and program which I tried.

I am trying to build multiple pie charts for columns 'Phase' and 'Peak' and data in pei to be 'Component' as label and 'Occurrence' as the sum.

In the given data, 'Phase' and 'Peak' are combinations where 'Component' is running. Every component will have its own count of occurrences.
Ex:

1. Phase1, Peak1, Comp1, does 35 read operations.
2. Phase1, Peak2, Comp1, does 45 read operations.
3. Phase1, Peak3, Comp1, does 54 read operations.
4. Phase2, Peak1, Comp1, does 33 write operations

Here you can see the Comp1 is common which is running on different 'Phase' and 'Peak'.

I want to group one pie chart for one set of Phase,Peak,Operation.

Looking at one Pie chart I should know which component is doing high number of Read on a Phase and Peak. Another pie chart for Write and so on.

The data is dynamic. Meaning, Phases, Peaks keeps changing. So the Pie plotting should be dynamic.

The scenario is like, Component is running on one of the TEST phases. TEST phase will be on one of the peaks. we need to identify all the components which are performing read/write operations.
You can imagine a TEST phase is a Server. Peak is another Server in which the TEST server is running.
It's just categorization of servers.

So its like PEAK->PHASE->Component which is doing read/write operations.

The pie charts should give us a picture on which component on which phase and peak is doing more/less number of read/write operations.

```
#Paste below code in https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypandas.asp?filename=demo_pandas_csv

#Three lines to make our compiler able to draw:
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

data = {"Phase": ["TEST", "TEST","TEST","TEST","TEST2","TEST2","TEST2","TEST3","TEST3","TEST3","TEST4","TEST4","TEST4","TEST4","TEST5"],
        "Peak": [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2],
        "Component": ["COMP1","COMP2","COMP3","COMP4","COMP5","COMP6","COMP7","COMP8","COMP9","COMP10","COMP11","COMP12","COMP13","COMP14","COMP15"],
        "Operation": ["READ","READ","READ","READ","READ","READ","WRITE","WRITE","WRITE","WRITE","WRITE","WRITE","WRITE","WRITE","WRITE"],
        "Occurrences":
        [4343,546,232,6675,343,7676,2323,565,343,232,676,45,343,223,44]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.Occurrences.groupby(df.Component).sum())
print(df.groupby(['Component','Occurrences','Phase','Operation']).sum())

plt.pie(df['Occurrences'],labels=df['Component'],autopct="%.2f")
#plt.axes().set_aspect("equal")
#plt.show()

#df.groupby(['Phase','Operation'])['Counter'].sum().plot.pie(subplots=True, autopct='%.1f%%')

#Two  lines to make our compiler able to draw:
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

With Above Code I am not able to group it as explained above. I guess for a python and matplotlib expert this is a simple task. Expecting some help. Thanks.